# TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined - Fetching data from restcountries API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, axios, frontend

I am building an app following the Rest Countries API challenge from [frontendmentor](https://www.frontendmentor.io/challenges/rest-countries-api-with-color-theme-switcher-5cacc469fec04111f7b848ca). I have run into a problem. When trying to find the border countries full name using the alpha3code, I get the error :
`TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined`.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import {Link} from "react-router-dom";
import {CountryDetailStyles, ImgContainer, CountryInfo, CountryInfoDetails, CountryDetailsWrapper, CountryInfoDetailsInner, CountryBorders, LinkWrapper} from "../styles/CountryDetailStyles";

function CountryDetail({match}) {
  useEffect(() => {
     fetchItem();
      
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
     setBorderCountries();
  }, []);

  const [item, setItem] = useState([]);
  const [allCountries, setAllCountries] = useState([]);

  const fetchItem = async () => {
    const response = await axios.get(`https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/name/${match.params.name}?fullText=true`);
    setItem(response.data)
  }

  const setBorderCountries = async () => {
    const response = await axios.get(`https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all`);
    setAllCountries(response.data)
  }

  // get borders full name using alpha3code
  const getBorderCountryName = (allCountries, border) => {
    const matchingCountry = allCountries.find(country => {
      return country.alpha3Code === border;
    })

    return matchingCountry.name;
  }

    
  return (
       <CountryDetailStyles>
           <Link className="country-links" to={"/"}>
             <LinkWrapper>
             <p><i className="fas fa-arrow-left"></i>Go Back</p>
             </LinkWrapper>
             </Link>
           {item.map(i => (   
               <CountryDetailsWrapper>           
               <ImgContainer flag={i.flag}>
               </ImgContainer>
               <CountryInfo>
                   <h1>{i.name}</h1>
                   <CountryInfoDetails>
                       <CountryInfoDetailsInner>
                       <p><span>Native Name: </span>{i.nativeName}</p>
                       <p><span>Population: </span>{i.population.toLocaleString()}</p>
                       <p><span>Region: </span>{i.region}</p>
                       <p><span>Sub Region: </span>{i.subregion}</p>
                       <p><span>Capital: </span>{i.capital}</p>
                       </CountryInfoDetailsInner>
                       <CountryInfoDetailsInner className="second">
                       <p><span>Top Level Domain: </span>{i.topLevelDomain}</p>
                       <p><span>Currencies: </span>{i.currencies[0].name}</p>
                       <p><span>Languages: </span>{i.languages.map(lang => lang.name).join(", ")}</p>
                       </CountryInfoDetailsInner>
                   </CountryInfoDetails>
                   <CountryBorders>
                       <p><span>Border Countries:</span></p>
                    {i.borders.map(border =>{
                      const borderName = getBorderCountryName(allCountries, border);
                      return (<Link to={`/country/${borderName}`}><button>{borderName}</button></Link>)
                    })}
                   </CountryBorders>
               </CountryInfo>
               </CountryDetailsWrapper>
           ))}
        </CountryDetailStyles>
  )
}

export default CountryDetail;
```

Comment: So `matchingCountry` here `const matchingCountry = allCountries.find` returning `undefined`

Comment: I think there is some issue in your fetchItem function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is here:

```
{item.map(i => (
```

you are getting this response from an axios call and setting in state which is this:

```
const response = await axios.get(`https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/name/${match.params.name}?fullText=true`);
    setItem(response.data)
```

on first render `item` doesn't have any data as axios call will take some time to complete and when there is no data an you try to iterate it then it will throw such error. So try this:

```
{
  ( item && item.length > 0 )  // conditional rendering or such type of check is neede before iteration
  ?
  // Iterate here
  :
  null // do nothing
}
```